# mongodb unwind and sort array nested inside an array of documents

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to make sorting functional well if it is case sensitive. how can we make it correct

Please suggest best way to fix it

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$receipe"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$receipe.burger"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "receipe.burger.name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/2pnUABI_-Mr

in my example familyburger should display first rather than Paneer Burger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vt3GQx0tdXC

- Add a new filed with to lower case using [$toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/)
- Sot on the lower case value

---

```
   db.products.aggregate([
      { "$unwind": "$receipe" },
      { "$unwind": "$receipe.burger" },
      { $addFields: { "insensitiveName": { $toLower: "$receipe.burger.name" } } },
      { $sort: { "insensitiveName": 1 } }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) option `caseLevel` in your query,

Flag that determines whether to include case comparison at strength level 1 or 2, If true, include case comparison.

```
db.products.aggregate(
  [
    { "$unwind": "$receipe" },
    { "$unwind": "$receipe.burger" },
    { "$sort": { "receipe.burger.name": 1 } }
  ],
  { collation: { locale: "en", caseLevel: true } }
)
```